# Can Redis Sentinel be used in AKS Kubernetescluster without persistent Volumes?

Tags: redis

I have a AKS Cluster and want to deploy Redis with Sentinel, one Master, two Replicas in my Infrastructure Nodepool with three Nodes, one Pod on each (currently doing that via NodeSelector).

I deploy Redis from the Bitnami Helm Chart with a custom values.yaml.

Redis is used purely as in cache Shorttime Key/Value Storage, no really Mission Critical Data is stored but a Redis downtime would still halt the whole Product so we still want the automatic Failover Benefits of Sentinel.

I noticed that while Updating there were Issues with unmounting the persistent Volumes on the old Nodes and mounting them on the new one causing pretty long timeouts and my current Understanding would be that we don't need those Persistent Volumes at all because the necessary Connection Information should be managed by Sentinel on the Replicas so I would just exlude them? Is that possible/advisable?

I found the Post REDIS cluster without persistence on KUBERNETES but I believe there a crutual differences between Sentinel and Cluster so I don't feel that answers my Question

Comment: Yes you can, but if you mount an emptyDir and the node became full, your pod(s) will be Evicted.

Comment: @benCat, why or how would that be connected?